# Rails gem simple_form - :wrapper_html showing up in compiled CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following form set up to use Twitter bootstrap stylings with the simple_form gem.  However, as you can see below, the "wrapper_html" command is visible in the compiled css and the Twitter bootstrap stylings are not being applied.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
<div class="formbox">
<h2>Sign Up To Hang Out With Some Losers<h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.input :email, :label => false, :placeholder => 'youremail@example.com', :wrapper_html => { :class => 'paddingmarg'} %>

  <%= f.submit "Get an invite", :wrapper_html => { :class => 'btn.btn-primary', :id => "invitation_button" } %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The compiled CSS....

```
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Get an invite" wrapper_html="{:class=&gt;&quot;btn.btn-primary&quot;, :id=&gt;&quot;invitation_button&quot;}">
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that submit doesn't use :wrapper_html because it's not input.

The class and id should just be passed directly like this.

```
<%= f.submit "Get an invite", :class => 'btn.btn-primary', :id => "invitation_button"  %>
```